# Cuando se accede como un tipo de usuario no se redirige a donde debería

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Si inicio como administrador tengo acceso a todos los módulos, pero al querer dirigirme no me manda al debería, estoy seguro que es un error de rutas.
Al igual tengo otro usuario denominado guardia, que solo tendría acceso a realizar observaciones, pero al dar clic para redirigir me manda a otros que no son, revise los controlador del login, pero este si esta correcto. Considero que el error esta en las rutas.
Estas son las rutas:

```html
class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={open:false};
    this.AuthService=new AuthService();
    this.logout=this.logout.bind(this);
    this.menuItems=[
      {icon:<HomeIcon></HomeIcon>,link:'/'},
      {icon:<StoreMallIcon></StoreMallIcon>,link:'/monitoreo'},
      {icon:<PaymentIcon></PaymentIcon>,link:'/sales'},
      {icon:<ShoppingCartIcon></ShoppingCartIcon>,link:'/purchases'},
      {icon:<GroupIcon></GroupIcon>,link:'/users'},
      {icon:<ShowChartIcon></ShowChartIcon>,link:'/reports'}
    ];
  }
  render(){
  const {classes}=this.props;
  const{open}=this.state;
  const userType=this.AuthService.getUserAccess();

  
  const sections=(userType==='Administrador')?['Inicio','Monitoreo','Catalogo Personal','Reportes','Accesos']:
                  (userType==='Guardia')?['Inicio','Reporte observaciones']:['Inicio','Reportes','Monitoreo'];
                  // (userType==='Auxiliar')?['Inicio','Reportes']:['Inicio','Reportes','Reporte observaciones','Monitoreo'];
  
  

  return (<Router>
    
        
      </Drawer>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <Switch>
                  <Route path='/' exact render={routeProps=><Home{...routeProps} propname={'p'}/>}></Route>
                  <Route path='/monitoreo' exact render={routeProps=><Monitoreo{...routeProps} propname={'m'}/>}></Route>                  
                  <Redirect from="*" to="/"/>
              </Switch>
      </main>
    </div>
    </Router>
```

Nota:
Los iconos no pertenecen, solo es una plantilla.

Comment: podrias agregar la parte del componente donde renderizas los modulos con react router

Comment: <Switch>
                  <Route path='/' exact render={routeProps=><Home{...routeProps} propname={'p'}/>}></Route>
                  <Route path='/monitoreo' exact render={routeProps=><Monitoreo{...routeProps} propname={'m'}/>}></Route>                  
                  <Redirect from="*" to="/"/>
              </Switch>

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema